# shell.openExternal is not opening valid URLs

Tags: macos, electron

I recently updated an Electron Mac app from Electron v5.0.1 to v9.0.1 and it seems that `shell.openExternal(url)` is no longer working. Nothing will open and an error will be logged to the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to open URL
```

This is on macOS 10.15.4 (Catalina). I couldn't find any useful information about this error online. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I think the problem @Tex0gen there is no protocol on the url like http://

Answer (score -2):

I was having this problem and solved it by getting `shell` with:

```
const { shell } = require('electron').remote
```

instead of just

```
const { shell } = require('electron')
```

Also on a Mac (macOS 11.1), although I'm not sure if that's particularly relevant since this is an issue of calling from a renderer process.